# Add claims to security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a SpringBoot `OAuth2` `Client` and `ResourceServer`. My `AuthorizationServer` is Okta.

Now suppose that in a certain moment I want to add a claim to my token, for Example:

```
@GetMapping("/addIdUser")
public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
  // here I want to add a claim to my Jwt, the token
  // should return to the frontend and when I resend back to my resourceserver
  // it should be validated again
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have read tons of docs of `TokenEnhencer` and `TokenConverter` but it not seems to be the solution I looking for.

Can I do something like this?

Comment: No, you can't, since you're not able to sign the JWT after modification. Only the authorization server issuing the JWT can.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to authorize based on domain specific claims, and there are two main options here:

- Get extra claims at the time of token issuance - Okta needs to either call an API or do a database lookup - this is the preferred option but not always possible
- Look up claims in the resource server when an access token is first received, then cache them for subsequent requests with the same access token

Leave the Okta issued token alone in the client, then adopt one of the above two approaches in the API. Out of interest, here is a Spring Boot API of mine that uses a library based approach to OAuth handling and implements both approaches:

- [Standard Authorizer](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/StandardAuthorizer.java)
- [Claims Caching Authorizer](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/ClaimsCachingAuthorizer.java)

Comment: I would simply like to add a piece of information that I can read at the (stateless) backend level. I don't want to change the Validation Mechanism or some others--